# How to iterate over Map<String,String> and Map<String,Map<String,String>> using the same recursion function?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, recursion, compiler-errors

for example, in order to iterate over List< String> and List< List< String>> using the same function,I can write something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void print(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof List){
            List list=(List)obj;
            System.out.print("[");
            for(Object obj2 : list){
                print(obj2);
            }
            System.out.print("]");
        }else{
            System.out.print(obj+",");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String l0="a";
        System.out.println(l0);

        List<String> l1=Arrays.asList("a","b");
        print(l1);

        System.out.println("");

        List<List<String> > l2=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a","b"),Arrays.asList("c","d"));
        print(l2);
    }
}
```

output:

```
a
[a b ]
[[a b ][c d ]]
```

Now I want to iterate over Map< String,String> and Map< String,Map< String,String>> similarly, I tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void print(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Map){
            System.out.print("{");
            Map map=(Map)obj;
            for(Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                print(entry.getKey());
                System.out.print(":");
                print(entry.getValue());
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print("}");
        }else{
            System.out.print(obj);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String m0="a";
        print(m0);

        System.out.println("");

        Map<String,String> m1=new HashMap<String,String>();
        m1.put("surname","Tom");
        m1.put("lastname","Bob");
        print(m1);

        System.out.println("");

        Map<String,HashMap<String,String>> m2=new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> mm1=new HashMap<String,String>();
        mm1.put("surname","Tom");
        mm1.put("lastname","Bob");
        mm1.put("nickname","Penguin");
        m2.put("owner",mm1);
        HashMap<String,String> mm2=new HashMap<String,String>();
        mm2.put("name","Lucky");
        mm2.put("type","cat");
        m2.put("pet",mm2);
        print(m2);
    }
}
```

which the expected output is something like:

```
a
{surname:Tom,lastname:Bob,}
{owner:{surname:Tom,nickname:Penguin,lastname:Bob,},pet:{name:Lucky,type:cat,},}
```

but it cannot compile:

```
Test.java:20: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Entry<Object,Object>
        for(Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
```

what is the reason? is it possible to fix it? if not, how can I iterate the nested map recursively like iterating List recursively at the beginning shown?

Comment: Why define an `Object` rather than a `Map` parameter in print() ?

Comment: Can you try: `Map<Object,Object> map=(Map)obj;`?

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` is not the same as a `Map<Object,Object>`.

It would either convert to `Map<Object,Object>` or use `Entry` without generics.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
public static void print(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Map){
        System.out.print("{");
        Map map=(Map)obj; // <-- raw map
   ....
```

you declare a raw `Map`.
It has important consequences as the compiler will bound the methods of the declared object without taking into consideration generics.

Here is the `entrySet()`  method declared in the `Map` interface :

```
Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
```

This method is so seen like :

```
Set entrySet();
```

So this code cannot compile :

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
```

since you manipulate a raw `Set`.

To solve your problem, you could cast the `Map` into a `Map<Object,Object>` or better  `Map<?, ?>` :

```
Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) obj;
for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    print(entry.getKey());
    System.out.print(":");
    print(entry.getValue());
    System.out.print(",");
}
```